# Is it possible to have more than one active environment for Dialogflow Messenger in Dialogflow ES?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I set up two environments for Dialogflow Messenger - a development environment and a production environment.  When I go to Dialogflow Messenger on the integrations page in Dialogflow ES, I see I can choose one environment, activate it, and then add the code to the site.

After it’s live, I will want to make more changes in the future and test in our dev site with the Dialogflow Messenger integration before going live, but I can’t set Dialogflow Messenger to point to the development environment without turning off production.  Is there another way to set this up where I can have two active environments?  I can’t use Web Demo because it doesn’t recognize the rich content used with Dialogflow Messenger.  I also don’t want to use the testing feature on the right side of the console as multiple people who don’t have logins will be testing.  Plus, testing through the console is not the true experience.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I played with the Dialogflow Messenger integration settings to learn I can’t have two active environments to have Dialogflow Messenger on.